# Why is SHA512Managed not FIPS Compliant?

Tags: .net, security, encryption, hash

As the title asks, why does SHA512Managed encryption cause an `InvalidOperationException` when the FipsAlgorithmPolicy is active on a machine?

Is it not secure enough for the FIP standard, or is it too secure?

Comment: similar (you know better than me if it's a dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080620/fips-hmac-sha512

Comment: It's similar but not really what I was looking for exactly.  I was more after an underlying reason for the error, not necessarily other code functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FIPS is not a single-standard but a wide set of standards.

"FIPS-compliant" is a redundant term - any implementation of the algorithm defined by FIPS is compliant, otherwise it would not interoperate with other implementations.

Now, there exists FIPS 140-2 - set of rules (mostly administrative and IT-related, rather than pure programming-related) that define what can be treated as "secure" environment.

Now we come closer ... The algorithm can be "FIPS-certified", that is approved by certified authority as the one that meets requirements of various standards including FIPS 140-2.

When you enable FIPS mode, you actually require that only FIPS-certified modules of Windows are used. And Windows does not have all crypto modules certified - certification is both expensive and time-consuming, so only certain set of native (non-managed) modules is certified, and only specific versions of those modules are certified.

So to put it simply - SHA512Managed class was not certified so it doesn't meet policy requirements.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  I am pretty un-knowledgeable about cryptography and encryption based security, so this was very informative.

Comment: I disagree with the definition of FIPS Compliant above - I would argue that "FIPS compliant" refers to whether the IMPLEMENTATION of the algorithm (in this case, SHA512Managed) is or uses only a FIPS-certified cryptographic module.  Non-FIPS-compliant code can interact with FIPS-compliant code (i.e. encrypt with one, decrypt with the other) - but  that doesn't make it compliant.  So even if you can interoperate SHA512Managed with SHA512CryptoServiceProvider, only SHA512CryptoServiceProvider is "FIPS-compliant" because it calls down to the FIPS-certified CryptoAPI foer the actual encryption.

Answer (score 3):

FIPS140-x deals with crypto modules in general, they're more about how much work went into verifying how well the crypto was implemented.

Now FIPS180-4 is all about Secure Hashing Standard, that's where you would find details about the SHA512 and all of its variants.  Maybe SHA512Managed doesn't do something that the FIPS180 agrees with, or maybe that mode of operation just wasn't evaluated.